# Fill Combobox with array of struct (CLR project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, clr, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on project for studies. I'm going to create Win Form app which will calculate material cost based on dimensions, mass etc. A month ago I made console app, but now I want to make "window" version. I'm going to assign array to my combobox but I got strange errors. How to solve this?

[Calculations.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BoTm.png)

[Calculations.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoKR4.png)

[Main.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jyD3.png)

My array is struct type ( I want set density of the material based on combobox material genre type) and I add value to first array item and have no idea how to add this to combobox.

Have a good day

Comment: Please do not post code as image. Please provide a [mre] plus some basic information on your compiler, OS, the error and warning messages your compiler generates. Also, please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use ref class. Please refer to the document: [Define and consume classes and structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-consume-classes-and-structs-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160) and [How to: Use Arrays in C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160).